# TextBox Accepts Tab key

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, textbox

If I set `TextBox` property `AcceptsTab` to `True` this condition in `TextBox_KeyDown` event isn't working.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
{
     if ((e.Control) && (e.Shift))
     {
         e.Handled = true;
         if (Tabs.SelectedIndex > 0)
             Tabs.SelectedIndex = Tabs.SelectedIndex - 1;
         else
             Tabs.SelectedIndex = Tabs.TabPages.Count - 1;
     }
     else if (e.Control)
     {
         e.Handled = true;
         if (chatFormTabs.SelectedIndex < chatFormTabs.TabPages.Count - 1)
             chatFormTabs.SelectedIndex = chatFormTabs.SelectedIndex + 1;
         else
             chatFormTabs.SelectedIndex = 0;
     }
}
```

I'd like this condition in Form KeyDown event but it's not working for me.

Can anyone suggest me how can I do that:

- TextBox will accepts tab key and add "\t" char to current position.
- I'll be able to change tabs by Ctrl+Tab or Ctrl+Shift+Tab.

Comment: Override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method.  How do you expect a user to ever discover this?

Answer (score 4):

Try the [PreviewKeyDown event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx). I had a similar issue (with accepting arrow keys) and it worked great.

Comment: This is the best solution. It saves you from having to derive your own control.

Comment: Basically, on `PreviewKeyDown` event you check `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) e.IsInputKey = true;`

Answer (score 3):

Textbox won't accept the tab unless you are in multi-line mode. Switch to multiline mode by setting the multiline property to true. Then, add the following in your KeyPress event of your textbox control.

```
if (e.KeyChar == '\t' || e.KeyChar== (char)13)
            e.Handled = true;
```

The above code means, don't do anything by default when tab or enter key is pressed.

After that, add the following code to your KeyDown event of your textbox control:

```
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
  {
     textBox1.AppendText(@"\t");
  }
```

Inside the braces of the above code, handle whatever you want to do when the tab key is pressed.

Comment: I have it now as you. But how I wrote in my question, now I cannot use `Ctrl+Tab` to change `Tabs`. And I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

[TextBox.TabStop Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff836316.aspx)
[TextBoxBase.AcceptsTab Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
You can use the TabStop property to specify whether you can use the TAB key to move the focus to a control. Read/write Boolean.